# Can overrideUserInterfaceStyle override system alerts / action sheets?

Tags: ios, ios13

Setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` doesn't seem to override the style for system alerts / action sheets, they can still be light when i set it to `.dark`, any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine if you set the `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` on the main window of your scene.

Update the `willConnectTo` method of your scene delegate to set the window's override:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Other existing code here

    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark // set as needed
}
```

This will show your app and various standard controls like action sheets in dark mode no matter which mode is selected in the Settings app.